# Different .gitconfig based on current path

Tags: git, zsh

In my `.zshrc` file I have a [`chpwd` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) that sets the [`GIT_CONFIG`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_environment) environment variable based on the current path.

Something like this:

```
update_gitconfig() {
  if [[ "$(pwd | grep -Poe '^/home/user/repositories/user-A(/|$)')" != "" ]]
  then
    export GIT_CONFIG="$HOME/.gitconfig-A"
    return
  fi

  if [[ "$(pwd | grep -Poe '^/home/user/repositories/user-B(/|$)')" != "" ]]
  then
    export GIT_CONFIG="$HOME/.gitconfig-B"
    return
  fi

  export GIT_CONFIG="$HOME/.gitconfig-default"
}

update_gitconfig
chpwd_functions+=(update_gitconfig)
```

If I run `git config --list`, it displays the expected configuration under every directory:

- Under `$HOME/repositories/user-A` it displays the settings from `$HOME/.gitconfig-A`.
- Under `$HOME/repositories/user-B` it displays the settings from `$HOME/.gitconfig-B`.
- Everywhere else, it displays the settings from `$HOME/.gitconfig-default`.

The problem begins when I run `git commit`; it doesn't seem to get the settings:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'user@host.(none)')
```

---

So, the question is:

**Is there any way to force `git commit` to get the info from the `$GIT_CONFIG` file?**

NOTE: I know I could run `git config` commands in the `chpwd` hook to apply local settings to every repository automatically, but I'm looking for a more "elegant" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git [v1.6.0 release note](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.0.txt#L41) contains a clue :

```
GIT_CONFIG, which was only documented as affecting "git config", but
actually affected all git commands, now only affects "git config".
```

And git v1.8.2 fixes that new behavior for `git clone` command which was still affected.

The workarounds I can see of interest are:

- Use git with as many users as needed *([`su`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) command-line tool can help)*.
- Writing aliases like `alias gitcommit='git commit --author=$(git config user.email)'` *(ugly)*.
- Copy your configuration file into your repo local configs *(any config modification must then be propagated by-hand)*.
- Fake `~/.gitconfig` lookup through `HOME` environment variable override. Ex: `HOME=~/.gitconfig/user-a/ git commit` should read `~/.gitconfig/user-a/.gitconfig` *(may have some other side effects)*.

Also, if you go with `chpwd` zsh hook, be careful to support multiple zsh running in multiple repositories.

Comment: these are ugly workarounds. The proper fix would be this: https://public-inbox.org/git/CANri+Ey71QbWxNH+RhMfYuUSDEpYtv28ushUhK8Tt0xWUAU9iw@mail.gmail.com/T/#u

Answer (score 1):

#### ~/.gitconfig:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Projects/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig_personal
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Projects/work/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

#### ~/gitconfig_personal:

```
[user]
    email = user@mail.com
    name = User Name
```

#### ~/gitconfig_work:

```
[user]
    email = user@work-mail.com
    name = User Name
```